# Enclose a rectangular image in a padded circle

Tags: css

I have images which are rectangular, of varying proportions and image sizes. I want to enclose them in a circle of 100x100px.

The blank space within the circle above and below the image padded with a background color.

So far I have this - it is almost there but the flag is not centered horizontally and the rounded corners should clip the flag.

```
  <div id="enclosure">
      <div id="image-container">
        <img src="http://aiatsis.gov.au/sites/default/files/images/galleries/aboriginal_flag/aboriginal_flag.jpg"/>
      </div>
  </div>

#enclosure {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 100px;
    background-color: white;
}

#image-container {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/sean123456789/jpcnony4/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `border-radius` is working on image container but not on the image so you need to use `overflow:hidden` in image container which will hide the part of the image goinf out of the div

```
#image-container {
    height: 0;
    padding-bottom: 100%;
    background-color: silver;
    border-radius: 50%;
    width: 100px;
    overflow:hidden
}
#image-container img {
  position:absolute;
  top:50%;
  left:50%;
  transform:translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

Working fiddle : https://jsfiddle.net/jpcnony4/4/

Comment: That's great! Now how can I move the flag down so it is centered across the middle. eg: http://mathcentral.uregina.ca/QQ/database/QQ.09.07/h/sridhar1.1.gif

Comment: for that we need to add css in image to center align it no matter what is the height and width. Here is the updated fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/jpcnony4/4/